# Data tables ajax post user selected parameters and reload table data

Tags: javascript, datatables-1.10, angular-datatables

I'm using Angular Data Tables (0.5.2) with DataTables 1.10.12  to load a Data Table instance. In the UI I provide a DatePicker (start and end date) for the user to select in order to limit the data by a date range. When the user click a submit button, my plan is to send a Data Tables ajax request back to the server to perform a new query including the start and end dates.

I have the Data Tables ajax.reload() working in the code below, however, I cannot get the start and end date values added to the ajax form post. I've tried several different configurations but none have worked. Can anyone suggest a working solution to simply invoke an ajax request with custom parameters to the server so that it can reprocess the request and send back updated results to Data Tables? Thanks!

```
//HTML
<table datatable="" dt-instance="vm.dtInstance" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" dt-columns="vm.dtColumns" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable"></table>

//CONTROLLER
function dashboardDownloadsCtrl($scope, dataService, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, DTInstanceFactory, DTRenderer) {
var vm = this;
vm.dtInstance = {};
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
.withDOM('<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp')
.withOption('ajax', {
type: 'POST',
dataSrc: 'data',
url: dataService.dashboard.downloads.route
})
.withOption('fnPreDrawCallback', function () { console.log('loading..') })
.withOption('fnDrawCallback', function () { console.log('stop loading..') })
.withOption('processing', true)
.withOption('serverSide', true)
.withOption('responsive', true)
.withPaginationType('full_numbers');

vm.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('RowNum').notVisible(),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('first_name').withTitle('First name'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('last_name').withTitle('Last name')
];
}

// Directive submit button click
$('button.applyBtn').click(function () {
var $el = $(this);
var startDate = $('.daterangepicker_start_input input').val();
var endDate = $('.daterangepicker_end_input input').val();
//get reference to controller
var dtVm = scope.$parent.vm;
var dtInstance = dtVm.dtInstance.DataTable;
// add start and end date picker values to ajax data source and call reload
dtVm.dtOptions.ajax.data = function(d) {
d.datepicker_start_date = startDate;
d.datepicker_end_date = endDate;
};
var resetPaging = true;
dtInstance.ajax.reload(function(json){
console.log('callback');}, resetPaging);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by simply adding the data method initialization. Apparently, this has to be set before you update the field values in the Ajax reload callback.

```
.withOption('ajax', {
        type: 'POST',
        dataSrc: 'data',
        url: dataService.dashboard.downloads.route,
        data: function (d) {
            d.datepicker_start_date = $('.daterangepicker_start_input input').val();
            d.datepicker_end_date = $('.daterangepicker_end_input input').val();
        }
    })
```